# How to push blob Google Script if Box is checked?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am working in Google Scripts I have the following snippets of code

```
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var driverPage = spreadsheet.getSheets()[6];
  var send1st = driverPage.getRange("E1").isChecked(); //should return true if box is checked
  var send2nd = driverPage.getRange("F1").isChecked(); //should return true if box is checked

 if(blob){
  attachmentArray.push(blob);
  if(send1st == "TRUE"){
  attachmentArray.push(schedulePDF);}
  if(send2nd == "TRUE"){
  attachmentArray.push(twoWeeksOut);}
  mailOptions.attachments = attachmentArray;
```

What I want to do is push schedulePDF and twoWeeksOut to the attachmentArray if their respective check boxes on the spreadsheet are checked. These snippets are part of a larger code that emails pay stubs and schedules. Right now, the schedules do not send regardless of the box being checked.

If I do

```
if(blob){
  attachmentArray.push(blob);
  if(send1st = "TRUE"){
  attachmentArray.push(schedulePDF);}
  if(send2nd = "TRUE"){
  attachmentArray.push(twoWeeksOut);}
  mailOptions.attachments = attachmentArray;
```

The schedules are sent regardless of being checked or not. Please provide any tips to where I went wrong or improvements. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- `isChecked()` returns a boolean value.
- In your script, `TRUE` of string value is compared with the boolean value.By this, the if statement is always `false`. I think that the reason of your issue is due to this.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

From:

```
if(blob){
 attachmentArray.push(blob);
 if(send1st == "TRUE"){
 attachmentArray.push(schedulePDF);}
 if(send2nd == "TRUE"){
 attachmentArray.push(twoWeeksOut);}
 mailOptions.attachments = attachmentArray;
```

To:

```
if(blob){
  attachmentArray.push(blob);
  if (send1st === true) {  // Modified
    attachmentArray.push(schedulePDF);
  }
  if (send2nd === true) {  // Modified
    attachmentArray.push(twoWeeksOut);
  }
  mailOptions.attachments = attachmentArray;
```

#### Other pattern:

When `getValue` and `getValues` are used, when the cell value is boolean, the retrieved values are also the boolean type. I think that this can be used for your situation.

```
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var driverPage = spreadsheet.getSheets()[6];
var [send1st, send2nd] = driverPage.getRange("E1:F1").getValues()[0];  // Modified
if(blob){
  attachmentArray.push(blob);
  if (send1st === true) {  // Modified
    attachmentArray.push(schedulePDF);
  }
  if (send2nd === true) {  // Modified
    attachmentArray.push(twoWeeksOut);
  }
  mailOptions.attachments = attachmentArray;
```

- In this case, it is required to know that the values of cells "E1" and "F1" are the checkbox.

#### References:

- [isChecked()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#ischecked)
- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)